# Como verifico os espaços em branco?

Tags: java, android

É um programa de média matemática, preciso de ajuda para verificar caso o usuário deixe em branco e clique no botão fazer média.

```
package suamedia.project.com.suamedia;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.EmptyStackException;

import static android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText primeiraNota;
    private EditText segundaNota;
    private TextView resultadoMedia;
    private Button botaoAcaoFinal;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Localizar os ids da tela
        primeiraNota = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recebeNotaUmId);
        segundaNota = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recebeNotaDoisId);
        botaoAcaoFinal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoMediaId);


        //adicionar um evento ao clicar no botão

        botaoAcaoFinal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                //Recuperar o que foi Digitado

                String textoDigitado1 = primeiraNota.getText().toString();
                String textoDigitado2 = segundaNota.getText().toString();
                Float resultadoParcial = Float.parseFloat(textoDigitado1);
                Float resultadoParcial2 = Float.parseFloat(textoDigitado2);
                Float resultadoFinal = (resultadoParcial + resultadoParcial2) / 2;




                if(textoDigitado1.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    //é nula, vazia ou só contém caracteres de espaço, tabulação e quebras de linha


                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
                    dialogo.setMessage("Insira as notas 1 ou 2!");
                    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
                    dialogo.show();
                    return;
                }if (textoDigitado2.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        //é nula, vazia ou só contém caracteres de espaço, tabulação e quebras de linha


                        AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
                        dialogo.setMessage("Insira as notas 1 ou 2!");
                        dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                        dialogo.setCancelable(false);
                        dialogo.show();
                        return;
                    }


                if((resultadoParcial > 10) && (resultadoParcial2 > 10)){


                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
                    dialogo.setMessage("Soma superior ao valor da média!");
                    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
                    dialogo.show();
                    return;

                }
                if ((resultadoParcial <= 10) && (resultadoParcial2 > 10)){

                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
                    dialogo.setMessage("Sua nota2 está superior ao valor permitido!");
                    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
                    dialogo.show();
                    return;

                }else
                    if((resultadoParcial2 <= 10) && (resultadoParcial > 10)){

                        AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
                        dialogo.setMessage("Sua nota1 está superior ao valor permitido!");
                        dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                        dialogo.setCancelable(false);
                        dialogo.show();
                        return;
                    }


                if ((resultadoFinal >= 8) && (resultadoFinal <= 10)) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
                    dialogo.setMessage("Excelente, você foi aprovado e está de parabéns, sua média foi: " + resultadoFinal + " Pontos.");
                    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
                    dialogo.show();
                }
                if ((resultadoFinal >= 7) && (resultadoFinal <= 7.9)) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
                    dialogo.setMessage("Razoável, você foi aprovado, mas pode melhorar, sua média foi: " + resultadoFinal + " Pontos.");
                    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
                    dialogo.show();

                } else if (resultadoFinal <= 6.9) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
                    dialogo.setMessage("Péssimo, você foi reprovado e está na final, sua média foi: " + resultadoFinal + " Pontos.");
                    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
                    dialogo.show();


                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ao abrir o programa feito em Android Studio e executar todas as tarefas ele funciona com exceção de verificação de espaços em brancos, ou seja clico em somar com os espaços em branco e o app fecha dando erros continuos[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E qual é o problema? Aparentemente o código faz isso. Aliás, evite usar "por favor, me ajudem", se você veio até aqui fazer uma pergunta, é óbvio que precisa de ajuda. Note também que este é o Stackoverflow **em português**, você não precisa escrever seus posts em dois idiomas. É importante que você seja mais específico na postagem, não dá pra entender qual o problema que está tendo, nem o que já tentou. Tente ser mais direto e mais explicativo.

Comment: entendi sou novo aqui também obrigado pelo esclarecimento , o código funciona em tudo , estou fazendo o aplicativo em Android Studio , e usando essa verificação em espaço em branco , porém ao executar o app e clicar em somar média com os espaços em branco o app fecha informando que o app tem vários problemas, ou seja não consegue verificar os espaços em branco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe nenhum erro em comparar se a *string* está vazia. O único erro é tentar usar o `Float.parseFloat` antes de conferir se existe espaço em branco no `EditText` ou realmente está vazia. Então é só passar as variáveis do tipo `Float` para depois que você verifica se os `EditTexts` estão vazios.

```
String textoDigitado1 = primeiraNota.getText().toString();
String textoDigitado2 = segundaNota.getText().toString();

if(textoDigitado1.trim().isEmpty() || textoDigitado2.trim().isEmpty()) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainTest.this);
    dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
    dialogo.setMessage("Insira as notas 1 ou 2!");
    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
    dialogo.show();

} else {

    Float resultadoParcial = Float.parseFloat(textoDigitado1);
    Float resultadoParcial2 = Float.parseFloat(textoDigitado2);
    Float resultadoFinal = (resultadoParcial + resultadoParcial2) / 2;
    .
    . 
    .
    // aqui você continua com seu código...
```

#### Dica extra:

Crie um método para exibição do alerta, como por exemplo `exibeAlerta()`. Assim você não precisa criar um `AlertDialog` para cada comparação. Veja:

```
public void exibeAlerta(String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainTest.this);
    dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
    dialogo.setMessage(message);
    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
    dialogo.show();
}
```

Para usar basta fazer desta forma:

```
if ((resultadoParcial > 10) && (resultadoParcial2 > 10)) {

    exibeAlerta("Soma superior ao valor da média!");
    return;

} else if ((resultadoParcial <= 10) && (resultadoParcial2 > 10)) {

    exibeAlerta("Sua nota2 está superior ao valor permitido!");
    return;

} else if ((resultadoParcial2 <= 10) && (resultadoParcial > 10)) {

    exibeAlerta("Sua nota1 está superior ao valor permitido!");
    return;
}

if ((resultadoFinal >= 8) && (resultadoFinal <= 10)) {

    exibeAlerta("Excelente, você foi aprovado e está de parabéns, sua média foi: " + resultadoFinal + " Pontos.");
} else if ((resultadoFinal >= 7) && (resultadoFinal <= 7.9)) {

    exibeAlerta("Razoável, você foi aprovado, mas pode melhorar, sua média foi: " + resultadoFinal + " Pontos.");

} else if (resultadoFinal <= 6.9) {
    exibeAlerta("Péssimo, você foi reprovado e está na final, sua média foi: " + resultadoFinal + " Pontos.");

}
```

Comment: Acklay você me salvou , quem sabe sabe , sou noob ainda em Java rsrsrs vlw.

Comment: Olá onde valido ?

Comment: @JeováEmanuel https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: ok vlw..consegui :D

Comment: @JeováEmanuel =D